# MySQL - Joining a table based on 2 keys from a Key/Value table

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have a table for settings, which can be shown as:
object_id (int)
key (varchar)
value (text)

I am trying to grab the object_id that has key's equal to 2 items.

```
SELECT `object_id` FROM `settings` WHERE `key` = 'A' AND `key` = 'B'
```

I know that won't work, the only way I can think of doing this is joining it on itself:

```
SELECT a.`object_id` FROM `settings` AS a LEFT JOIN `settings` AS b ON ( a.`object_id` = b.`object_id` ) WHERE a.`key` = 'A' and b.`key` = 'B'
```

While I haven't tested the last statement, I'm sure something like this could work. This query will be performed on potentially hundreds of thousands of records every hour, so I want to keep it optimized -- is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, you want:

```
  SELECT `object_id` 
    FROM `settings`  
   WHERE (`key` = 'A' AND `value`='foo') 
      OR (`key`= 'B' AND `value`='bar')
GROUP BY `object_id`
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Use:

```
  SELECT `object_id` 
    FROM `settings`  
   WHERE `key` IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY `object_id`
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `key`) = 2
```

Or:

```
SELECT x.`object_id` 
  FROM `settings` AS x 
  JOIN `settings` AS y ON y.`object_id` = x.`object_id`  
 WHERE x.`key` = 'A' 
   AND y.`key` = 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks -- exactly what I was looking for -- would it be possible to specify values to match those keys? if `key` = 'a' AND `value` = 'b'?

Comment: @Kerry: Sorry?  Those are distinct columns & values, no need for a JOIN or GROUP BY/HAVING

Comment: Yeah -- my mind is a bit muddled right now, drawing a few blanks, thanks -- your solutions are perfect (didn't know the first was possible)

Comment: @Kerry: yes, just add as seperate clauses: ` WHERE (\`key\` = 'A' AND \`value\`='foo') OR (\`key\`= 'B' AND \`value\`='bar')`

Comment: @ Wrikken -- its needs both keys to exist and have designated value -- not one or the other. I worded the question poorly but @OMG Ponies answered the question as I asked it which gave me some good data to work with.

Comment: @Kerry: So you mean: `WHERE `key` IN ('A', 'B') AND `value` = 'foo'`?  That's fine as is

Comment: `key = 'a' AND value = 'foo' AND key = 'b' AND value = 'bar'` (obviously two different records). I think the only way to do it is with a join.

Comment: Heh - last answer was perfect. Sorry for the confusion.